# Gauss' Law in differential form applied to charged sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I need to use the differential form of Gauss' Law $$\nabla · \vec E = \rho / \epsilon $$ applied to a charged sphere to obtain that the exterior field is given by $$\vec E = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon r^2 } \hat r .$$ I understand it's easier with the integral form but this must be strictly done with the differential form. I tried approaching the problem like one would do with the charged plaque. However, I got nowhere. I would appreciate any help given, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is ill posed. The divergence operator is not generally invertible. There are many functions with the same divergence.

We need further information of electric field on a region of space plus some symmetry considerations to invert the differential equation for the electric field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said sphere, and not shell, you'll have a total charge $Q$ uniformly distributed over the sphere of radius $R$:

$$\rho=\frac Q{\frac 4 3 \pi R^3}$$

Based on symmetry:

$$ \vec E(r,\theta, \phi) = E(r)\hat r$$

Moreover:

$$ E(0) = 0$$

So, starting at the center, we have:

$$ \nabla \cdot\vec E = \frac 1{r^2}\frac{d( r^2E(r))}{dr}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

From there you get:

$$ E(r) \propto r $$

and you can figure out the constant of proportionality.

That holds up to $r=R$.

For $r>R$:

$$ \nabla \cdot\vec E = \frac 1{r^2}\frac{d( r^2E(r))}{dr}=0$$

so the derivative should act on a constant function. Thus:

$$ E(r) \propto \frac 1 {r^2}$$

Then piece it all together. No integrals and no delta functions, in spite of the discontinuity in $\rho(r)$ at $r=R$.

Comment: For OP, symettry can only be inferred by assuming the curl is also zero.

Comment: And the fields must also vanish at infinity for this assumption to be made aswell I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I have just one question, how can you get the constant of proportionality? I understood up to $\frac{d(r^2 E(r))}{dr} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}r^2E(r) = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dr}r^2E(r) = r^2\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$$

$$r^2E(r) = \frac{1}{3}r^3\frac{\rho}{
\epsilon_{0}} + c_{1}$$

$$E(r) = \frac{1}{3}r\frac{\rho}{
\epsilon_{0}} + \frac{c_{1}}{r^2}$$


 the  condition that $E(0)= 0$
Gives $c_{1} = 0$

$$\rho = \frac{Q}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3} $$


$$E(r) = \frac{Qr}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}R^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a point charge $\rho = Q\delta^3(r)$

You need to technically use

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$$
$$\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$$

Although more complicated, if you really want to use the differential equations:

$\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$

$\vec{E} = -\nabla V$

$\nabla \cdot (-\nabla V) = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$

$$\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$$

Which is poissons equation for electrostatics.

Technically we need to also apply the condition that $\vec{E}(\infty) = 0$ to determine a unique solution.

$$V(\vec{r}) = \iiint \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{\rho(r')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} d^3 r' $$

$$V(\vec{r}) = \iiint \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q\delta^3(r')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} d^3 r' $$

$$V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{|\vec{r}|} $$

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = -\nabla V = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{|\vec{r}|^2} \hat r$$

Comment: Here is the proof without using any direct symettry arguements. However JEBS, proof is much simpler, and is more inline with the standard method in integral form of obtaining E but in differential form. As by saying E and da are in the same direction, you are effectively saying $\vec{E} = E(r)\hat r$

Comment: Thanks. Your comment helped me a lot in understanding JEB's proof. Also, your method is very direct as well, I'm a bit lost with the Dirac Delta function but it's always good to learn new things.

Comment: I hadn't actually read the part about a charged sphere, so my answer is actually about a point charge. Replacing rho to some constant charge density and integrating about a sphere yields the same answer though, for r>R as it has the same spherical symettry. (It's important to  note that symmetry  arguements can only be made assuming there's no curl, and also  no homogenous solution exist ( hence the condition that E,V=0 at infinity) this is because maxwells equations are not uniquely determined, without boundary conditions  as e.g maxwells equations allow certain field overlayed ontop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, for a point-like charge, $\rho$ would be a very strange function that's zero everywhere except on the charge, and infinite on the charge.

The only way to describe that properly is to use a distribution, so that $\rho(\vec{r})=Q\delta(\vec{r})$.

Comment: Remember it's a three dimensional delta function

Comment: I know, but indicating the dimension on $\delta$ isn't mandatory, and the point (mine and yours, it seems) was that usage of a distribution is required. The technical details depend on on the math level of the top poster.

Comment: Thought I'd point it out, as OP probably hasn't seen the dirac function before, and may get confused.

Comment: Oh OK, I understand. Saying the same things with more casual physics words, let's say that $\delta$ can be written as $\delta^3$ because, like $\rho$, it's a volume density.

Comment: $\delta^3(r') = \delta(x')\delta(y')\delta(z')$ more necessary, than a notational trick.